# Quicklook for Live Photo?

Tags: ios, swift, quicklook, phlivephoto

The docs says you can use Quicklook to view Live Photos. Overview section
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook

I searched and could not an example on how to do it in swift.
Seems like have to use PHLivePhotoView to view Live Photo.
Is that true?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL to a Live Photo on disk, you can use Quick Look to display it. If you have a PHLivePhoto / PHAsset etc. , you need to use PHLivePhotoView.